# Im trying to figure out why my code exceeds 4 seconds in certain cases

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a test on codesignal. safe to say I'm going to fail this question, it's my only question left and I spent all my time on it. time is running out I think it should be alright to ask for help at this point as I don't know what else to do. Here is my code and the comments explain what the goal is. The goal is to figure out the greatest length you can cut the ribbons(a) to get at least (k) pieces.
My main issue is for certain hidden tests, the time limit of 4 seconds is exceeded. but when I run performance.now() all of the visible tests are below 0.09 seconds at most. I can't figure out why.

```
function solution(a, k) {
  // the logic here is to determine the biggest size (in length) you can cut the 
  // ribbons(a) into atleast(k) amount of pieces.
  
  // for example a = [1,2,3,4,5]; k = 5 lets use 1 length.
  // 1 - 1 = 0
  // 2 - 1 - 1 = 0
  // 3 - 1 -1 -1 = 0
  // 4 - 1 - 1 -1 -1 = 0
  // 5 - 1 - 1 - 1 -1 -1 = 0, this results in 15 pieces. lets narrow it down with 2
  // 1 - 2 = -1 (this will have to be avoided somehow. for example if a[i] > length)
  // 2 - 2 = 0
  // 3 - 2 = 1 (rule will stop it here thanks to previous example)
  // 4 - 2 -2 = 0
  // 5 - 2 - 2 = 1 (rule will stop it here thanks to previous example)
  //
  // this will result in 6 pieces. can we narrow it down further? lets try 3.
  // we can skip 1 & 2 as the rule will do so too.
  // 3 - 3 = 0
  // 4 - 3 = 1
  // 5 - 3 = 2 this results in 3 pieces. this is not enough pieces. we need a rule in place to invalid this, if the number of pieces is not greater or equal to k.
  
  // we will use a loop test to give us the greatest number, while making a rule that it must be greater than k.
  // then we return the value of test

  let l = 1; // (the length)
  let test = 1000000000;
  let answer;
  while (l < 1000000000) {
    testArr = a.slice();
    let pieces = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
      testArr[i] /= l;
      pieces += parseInt(testArr[i]);
    }

    if (pieces < k) {
      l = 1000000000;
    } else {
      if (pieces <= test) {
        test = pieces;
        answer = l;
        console.log(`${l}in for ${pieces} pieces`);
      }
      l++;
    }
  }
  var endTime = performance.now();
  console.log(`it look ${endTime} milliseconds`);
  return answer;
}
```

the constraints of the problem are between 1 & 10 to the 9th power.
I used performance.now() to test the speed, and every visible test i below 0.09 seconds. so im lost why certain hidden test exceed the time limit of 4 seconds.
this code works for all of the visible test, but there are hidden test that are not passing, and i cant figure out for the life of me why. is it because its too slow? what can i remove or replace to speed it up IF thats the issue? or is there another issue i am blind too?

Im not exactly sure, as the hidden test are well hidden. But i could say i was expecting my code to be faster?

Comment: The nested looping seems troublesome. I haven't fully understood your logic, but if `a` is long, say even 1000 items and you reach your worst case scenario, you will loop 1 trillion times?

Comment: @Tom I should also add, parameter k will be at least 1 with a limit of 10 to 9th power as well. so eventually, var pieces will =  0, so it won't loop forever. But yes I understand these loops are confusing, I'm still a beginner.  the limit for the loop originally was 1000. I increased it to 1 trillion to compensate for the constraints provided by the problem, incase the reason it failed was because the answer exceeded 1000. but that didn't solve all my issues

Comment: Instead of `l++`, use a binary search principle, where you first *double* `l` each time until you overreach, and then you have a min-max range for `l` (as half of  it is the lower bound) on which you can continue with a normal binary search algorithm. This way you have fewer iterations.

Comment: @trincot Thank you, I will look into that, as I am not familiar with binary search principle, Im going to revisit the problem after looking it up and give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to count the number of chunks that have at least size .

In your algorithm the `l++` step makes it slow: this is a linear search, and `l` might need to increase a lot that way. You'll get better efficiency if you use binary search. The lower bound for the length is obviously 1. The upper bound can be set to the size of the largest ribbon in the input.

Here is an idea of the code. As your question only had one test case, I didn't really test this code, but the idea should be clear:

```
function solution(a, k) {
    // determine the greatest size (in length) you can cut the 
    // ribbons(a) into, such that you get at least k amount of pieces.

    let high = a.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b));
    let low = 1; 
    while (low <= high) {
        const mid = (low + high) >> 1;
        let numPieces = 0;
        for (const size of a) {
            numPieces += Math.floor(size / mid);
        }
        if (numPieces < k) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return high;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I tested the code with sample tests & this works, although my beginner brain doesn't quite understand why yet. I will have to look into how Math functions and reduce work. I will do my best to fully understand them and not just copy the code when I am allowed to retake the test. Thanks again